# c# DocumentLoadedEvent not firing

Tags: c#

I want my program to get the latitude and longitude of the ISS from a website, so I have the following code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Speech.Synthesis;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Net;

 namespace myprogram
 {
        class Program
        {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                       try
                       {
                              WebBrowser browser1 = new WebBrowser();
                              browser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

                              browser1.Url = new Uri("https://isstracker.spaceflight.esa.int/");
                              browser1.Visible = true;
                              browser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                              browser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                              browser1.AllowNavigation = false;
                       }
                       catch (Exception e) 
                       {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                       }

                       Main(null); //don't know if this is the best way to keep the program from closing
                }
                static void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("iss page loaded");
                     if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
                         return;
                     string lat = (sender as WebBrowser).Document.GetElementById("isst_lat").InnerText;
                     string lon = (sender as WebBrowser).Document.GetElementById("isst_lon").InnerText;
                     Console.WriteLine("latitude is" + lat + ",longitude is" + lon);
        
                }
        }
 }
```

When I run the program, the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEvent` doesn't fire. I have looked for solutions, but have not found one.
If anyone has a soultion, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting? At least, like, trying to sketch out the problem. Cause seeing the code, and only the code, I can think of many potential isssues.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't fire?

Comment: What kind of application is this (Winforms, Console, WPF, something else)?  Does it throw a stack overflow exception?

Comment: Why don't you just query [the json feed](http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json)?

Comment: Remove the Main(null) Statement which may be giving issue.  Temporarily put in Console.Readline(); to block.  You can add   Use following to block : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-5.0

Comment: The WebBrowser control is a Windows Forms control.  It expects to be part of a WinForms app.  If you want to use that control, use WinForms.  Everything should mostly _just work_ in that environment.  @Crowcoder's suggestion is probably the simplest way to go (for a Console app).  Use an HttpClient instance and hit the JSON endpoint.  Your call to `Main(null)` is a really bad idea (think about it, from within Main, you call Main, which, when it gets to the end will call Main again, and so on). As noted by jdweng, a call to `Console.ReadLine` is generally the right way to block a console app.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, your program exits before it does, actually, fires "document loaded" event, or even, it throws a Stack Overflow exception (not rly... it's maximum call stack exceeded, i guess... can't remember it).

Now, answering your questions:

1st. See, your program is a Console App, instead of a Windows Forms App.
check out each the difference between them (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-teleprompter and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) and notice they are way way different.
So If you want to see the web browser it self, you should be using windows forms application.
Instead, if you are just willing to parse and transform the Response of a Web Request (I guess thats the case here), google "WebClient.DownloadString Tutorial" and enjoy. ;)

2nd. This is not the best way to keep your program from closing... Since you've commented it ("//don't know if this is the best way to keep the program from closing") I'll point you to some clarifying directions...

Back in the day when we programmers used to drink soda in cork closed bottles, ride horses bareback, hunt our food and stuff, programs used to be called "command prompt"... is like git bash where you need to know the commands to use them in a "no user interface" environment...

yep! there was **NO USER INTERFACE**! you had to really type each command (like clicking a button), and pass the parameters (the stuff you put inside a textbox, or a checkbox checked state, for instance) in a single line to do anything...
It has been like forever, but the scars (lessons learned) are still with us!

One way to keep your console from closing (can't tell you the "best"! sure can tell you the one I like best!) is to listen to commands... While the user inputs text lines, you check if this line is a valid command, and tells him if it's not. If the user inputs your valid "Exit" command, it shuts... (hint: the words "While" and "If" are actual programming patterns to be implemented)

So, this is a "guidelines answer", not the "programming done it self"... if wou need it done, just comment here and I can give it a try for you...
Just an advice: It is better learning than being prisioner to other's help.